# Meaning of "second employee"

Tags: meaning

What does the writer mean here by "second employee" in the below sentence?

> Later that year, I left my job as the second employee at Pinterest–before I vested any of my stock–to turn it into what I thought would become my life’s work.

Comment: Perhaps it means "the second person to be given employment (by a new company)".

Answer (score 4):

It seems to mean the writer was the second person to be employed by Pinterest (i.e., one of Pinterest's first employees).